# For my character selection to work I need to refresh the character prefab in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, 2d, game-engine

My character selection script is meant to change the player prefab . To access it I use this script that is programmed to change the player sprite.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SkinManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public SpriteRenderer sr;
    public SpriteRenderer displaysr;
    public List<Sprite> skins = new List<Sprite>();
    private int selectedskin = 0;
    public GameObject playerskin;








    public void Start()
    {
        
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Selected_skin"))
        {
            
            selectedskin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Selected_skin");
            sr.sprite = skins[selectedskin];
        }
       
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedskin];

        sr.sprite = displaysr.sprite;

    }

    public void NextOption()
    {
        selectedskin = selectedskin + 1;

        if (selectedskin == skins.Count)
        {
            selectedskin = 0;

        }
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedskin];
        displaysr.sprite = skins[selectedskin];
    }



    public void Update()
    {

    }




    public void BackOption()
    {
        selectedskin = selectedskin - 1;
        if (selectedskin < 0)
        {
            selectedskin = skins.Count - 1;
        }
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedskin];
        displaysr.sprite = skins[selectedskin];
    }






    public void PlayGame()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Selected_skin") == false)
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Selected_skin", selectedskin);
        }




        SceneManager.LoadScene("LevelSelection");

    }
}
```

if anyone of you guys can help me it will be a really good help . Please give me another script version

Comment: So what exactly is the issue/question?

Comment: so the sprite of the playerprefab does not want to output the selected character

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your player is a DontDestroyOnLoad Object and from what it looks like you have a whole texture for your Player I would do this:

```
//Assuming SkinManager is on the Player object (I left out the default using tags)
using UnityEngine.UI;

public SkinManager : MonoBehavior
{
    //In this example skins[0] is the default skin
    public List<Sprite> skins;
    public SpriteRenderer sr;
    int selectedSkin;

    void Start()
    {
        sr.sprite = skins[0];
    }

    //As this is probably for a button I made it public
    public void NextOption()
    {
        //Check if we have reached the maximum BEFORE(your previous error) and if so reset
        if(selectedSkin == skins.Count - 1/*-1 due to the fact the total number is returned not the last index*/)
            selectedSkin = 0;
        else
            selectedSkin++;
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedSkin];
    }

    public void PreviousOption()
    {
        if(selectedSkin == 0)
            selectedSkin = skins.Count - 1;
        else
            selectedSkin--;
        sr.sprite = skins[selectedSkin];
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, can you try to show me a good tutorial that it's purpose is to change the main player sprite?

Comment: @RayanHilali sorry for the late answer but I have worked on Projects outside of Unity for a bit but I can work on a solution that should work

Comment: thank you very much and can you send me the code when you finish it? my email is: rayan.hilali@gmail.com

Comment: @RayanHilali I will send it as soon as I can I am currently not at home but today I am driving back and should be able to finish a working example